# jQuery.get difference between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, cross-domain

I am trying to use a simple $.get request to get data from the server.

```
$('#api')[0].contentWindow.$.get(
    '/get_url'
    function(data) { 
    },
    'json'
);
```

$('#api') is an iframe here, loading a subdomain of my website. I have set document.domain of both the parent page and the iframe to the same value, to be able to make cross sub-domain requests.

This works with no problem on Chrome, however on Firefox the callback is never fired, and I see no error messages on the Firebug console. The request is returned with 200 OK code.

Response header contains Content-Type: application/json . I am also forcing the expected content type to be json in the above code. I have checked the returned json using jsonlint and it validates the json.

I have seen several questions of people facing similar issues, but in their case the problem was solved with either setting the content-type response header or adding 'json' to the get request. However, that does not change a thing in my case.

I am using jquery version 1.7.1, and on the backend I am using django 1.3.1.

This is a sample json response returned from the server

```
{
    "parameter": "value",
    "parameter": integerValue,
    "list": [
        {
            "name": "value"
        },
        {
            "name": "value"
        },
        {
            "name": "value"
        }
    ],
    "parameter": "value"
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try `contentDocument` instead of `contentWindow` may work for you

Comment: contentDocument seems to be undefined